# SSMS doesn't show all installed Instances

Tags: ssms

I've installed two named instances (SQLEXPRESS & MSSQLSERVER) but in SMSS, it only shows SQLEXPRESS when I try to connect.

How can I connect to MSSQLSERVER from SMSS.

Note. SQLEXPRESS was installed first.

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind. I found this.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/219069-sql-server-2008-cannot-connect-to-my-instance-in-management-studio/